# Why does finding the eigenvalues of a 4*4 matrix by z3py take so much time and do not give any solutions?

Tags: matrix, eigenvalue, z3py

I'm trying to calculate the eigenvalues of a 4*4 matrix called A in my code (I know that the eigenvalues are real values). All the elements of A are z3 expressions and need to be calculated from the previous constraints. The code below is the last part of a long code that tries to calculate matrix A, then its eigenvalues. The code is written as an entire but I've split it into two separate parts in order to debug it: part 1 in which the code tries to find the matrix A and part 2 which is eigenvalues' calculation. In part 1, the code works very fast and calculates A in less than a sec, but when I add part 2 to the code, it doesn't give me any solutions after.

I was wondering what could be the reason? Is it because of the order of the polynomial (which is 4) or what? I would appreciate it if anyone can help me find an alternative way to calculate the eigenvalues or give me some hints on how to rewrite the code so it can solve the problem.

(Note that A2 in the actusl code is a matrix with all of its elements as z3 expressions defined by previous constraints in the code. But, here I've defined the elements as real values just to make the code executable. In this way, the code gives a solution so fast but in the real situation it takes so long, like days.
for example, one of the elements of A is almost like this:

```
0 +
 1*Vq0__1 +
 2 * -Vd0__1 +
 0 +
 ((5.5 * Iq0__1 - 0)/64/5) * 
 (0 +
  0 * (Vq0__1 - 0) +
  -521702838063439/62500000000000 * (-Vd0__1 - 0)) +
 ((.10 * Id0__1 - Etr_q0__1)/64/5) * 
 (0 +
  521702838063439/62500000000000 * (Vq0__1 - 0) +
  0.001 * (-Vd0__1 - 0)) +
 0 +
 0 + 0 +
 0 +
 ((100 * Iq0__1 - 0)/64/5) * 0 +
 ((20 * Id0__1 - Etr_q0__1)/64/5) * 0 +
 0 +
 -5/64
```

All the variables in this example are z3 variables.)

```py
from z3 import *
import numpy as np


def sub(*arg):
    counter = 0
    for matrix in arg:
        if counter == 0: 
            counter += 1
            Sub = [] 
            for i in range(len(matrix)):
                Sub1 = []
                for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
                    Sub1 += [matrix[i][j]]
                Sub += [Sub1]
        else:
            row = len(matrix)
            colmn = len(matrix[0])
            for i in range(row):
                for j in range(colmn):
                    Sub[i][j] = Sub[i][j] - matrix[i][j]  
    return Sub

Landa = RealVector('Landa', 2) # Eigenvalues considered as real values
LandaI0 = np.diag(  [ Landa[0] for i in range(4)]  ).tolist()

ALandaz3 = RealVector('ALandaz3', 4 * 4 )

############# Building ( A - \lambda * I ) to find the eigenvalues ############

A2 = [[1,2,3,4],
      [5,6,7,8],
      [3,7,4,1],
      [4,9,7,1]]

s = Solver()

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        s.add( ALandaz3[ 4 * i + j ] == sub(A2, LandaI0)[i][j] )
ALanda = [[ALandaz3[0], ALandaz3[1], ALandaz3[2], ALandaz3[3] ],
          [ALandaz3[4], ALandaz3[5], ALandaz3[6], ALandaz3[7] ],
          [ALandaz3[8], ALandaz3[9], ALandaz3[10], ALandaz3[11]],
          [ALandaz3[12], ALandaz3[13], ALandaz3[14], ALandaz3[15] ]]
Determinant = (
 ALandaz3[0] * ALandaz3[5] * (ALandaz3[10] * ALandaz3[15] - ALandaz3[14] * ALandaz3[11]) -
 ALandaz3[1] * ALandaz3[4] * (ALandaz3[10] * ALandaz3[15] - ALandaz3[14] * ALandaz3[11]) +
 ALandaz3[2] * ALandaz3[4] * (ALandaz3[9]  * ALandaz3[15] - ALandaz3[13] * ALandaz3[11]) -
 ALandaz3[3] * ALandaz3[4] * (ALandaz3[9]  * ALandaz3[14] - ALandaz3[13] * ALandaz3[10]) )

tol = 0.001 

s.add( And( Determinant >= -tol, Determinant <= tol ) )   # giving some flexibility instead of equalling to zero

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Comment: Your code doesn't load as is in z3py. Names `A` and `A2` are unbound, there are syntax errors. (Definition of `Determinant` isn't syntactially correct, it ends halfway through.) Your constraint `And(Determinant >= tol, Determinant <= tol)` means you want `Determinant` to be exactly `tol`, which is probably not what you meant. The calls to `s.check()` and `s.model()` should be wrapped in `print`, etc. Please fix all these issues and post a standalone loadable code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @JohanC. I've edited the code. As I've mentioned, A2 is originally a matrix of 16  z3 expressions but here in order to make the code executable, I've defined this A2 matrix with some real values.

Comment: Thanks, @alias, I've fixed the issues you mentioned.

Comment: Great.. But now when I run it, it quickly finishes and prints a bunch of values. For stack-overflow questions to work well, you need to really post something that exhibits the issue.

Comment: Could you at least describe how these expressions inside A2 look like? (Preferably you create an executable example that takes too much time.) Do you need solutions for the eigenvalues? Or for the variables inside the expressions?  Note that Z3 only gives one solution, and doesn't return equations. Sympy could return equations.

Comment: @JohanC, I need to find the solutions for the eigenvalues but the cells of matrix A are also z3 expressions calculated from previous constraints.

Comment: It looks like you've too many variables to make this work, nor with Z3 nor with sympy, I even think that in general it will not be possible to express the eigenvalues in function of these variables. Even a third degree polynomial has overly complex expressions for its roots. Adding the constraint `-tol < Determinant < tol` makes it even much more infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you seem to be using Z3 for a type of equations it absolutely isn't meant for. Z is a [sat/smt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) solver. Such a solver works internally with a huge number of boolean equations. Integers and fractions can be converted to boolean expressions, but with general floats Z3 quickly reaches its limits. See [here](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/advanced-examples.htm) and [here](https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf) for a lot of typical examples, and note how floats are avoided.

Z3 can work in a limited way with floats, converting them to fractions, but doesn't work with approximations and accuracies as in needed in numerical algorithms. Therefore, the results are usually not what you are hoping for.

Finding eigenvalues is a typical numerical problem, where accuracy issues are very tricky. Python has libraries such as [numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) to efficiently deal with those. See e.g. [`numpy.linalg.eig`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html).

If, however your `A2` matrix contains some symbolic expressions (and uses fractions instead of floats), [sympy](https://www.sympy.org)'s [matrix functions](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html#eigenvalues-eigenvectors-and-diagonalization) could be an interesting alternative.

Comment: I had similar thoughts, but z3 can indeed be an interesting choice here: Imagine you know some of the numbers of the matrix but not all, and you require all eigenvectors to be real. You can use z3 to "suggest" what those entries might be. But you're right that the way the question is posed (and given it's full of syntactic errors and doesn't load as is), it's hard to guess what the OP is intending to do.